# How do I check if a program is running in bash?

Tags: bash, function, netcat

I have made a chat-script in bash and I want to check whether or not `netcat` is running.

I've tried `pgrep` but and it's working but it prints out an error in the terminal but it still keeps going like normal.

This is a part of that script:

```
function session()
{

    echo -n "Port (default is 3333): "
    read port

    if [ -n "${port}" ]
    then
        clear
        echo "Only 2 users can talk to each other simultaneously."
        echo "To send a message, simply write and hit enter. Press Ctrl+C to quit."

        nc -l -p ${port}

        if [ pgrep "nc -l -p ${port}" ]
        then
            echo "${l_name} logged in to chat session"
        else
            clear
            new
        fi
    else
        echo "Invalid port!"
        new

    fi
}
```

Comment: `service netcat status`?

Comment: What error does it print out? what is the return code from pgrep when you run it?

Comment: Never mind, I was just missing some characters in the if statement.

Comment: You need to use the `-f` option to `pgrep` to match the whole command line. By default it just matches the program name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `prep` inside `[ ]`. That doesn't run the `prep` command, it just treats the word `pgrep` as an argument to the `test` command.

You also need to use the `-f` option to make `pgrep` match the entire command line, not just the program name.

It should be

```
if pgrep -f "nc -l -p ${port}"
then
    ...
else 
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run script with a "-x" parameter. This shows each line that runs. Here is a description from man page:

> -x   :   After expanding each simple command, for command,  case 
>   command,  select  command,  or arithmetic  for command, display the
>   expanded value of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded
>   arguments or associated word list.

Here is an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( ls ); do
    echo item: $i
done
```

If you run with **-x** you can see each command running with a head of + sign:

```
$ bash -x list.sh
++ ls
+ for i in '$( ls )'
+ echo item: list.sh
item: list.sh
```

Comment: How would the script make use of this to check if `netcat` is running?

Comment: When you run the script, you can see which commands are ran as and output. Your `netcat` command will be logged if it was running.

Comment: Yeah, but he wants the script itself to be able to tell if netcat is running, so it can do something with `if`.